# How to retrieve all contacts from ABAddressBook without duplicates

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, abaddressbook

To get all contacts I'm using `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` method but, this method return all contacts with duplicates: in "Contacts" app I saw that almost every my contacts has linked card (it's show me that I have two same contacts one from iCloud and an other from my iPad). As I see in this reason `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople` method return duplicate contacts.
How to get all contacts from ABAddressBook without duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the [ABContactHelper](https://github.com/erica/ABContactHelper) could help?!

Answer (score 1):

From memory I think this returns only one record per user:

```
    ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
    addressBookArray = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByLastName);
```

I've used it an it appears to work.  Although you will have to jump through the linked contacts to get all the details about a user.

Remember to CFRelease source and addressBook when you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did not find another solution then the manual bidirectional-link-duplicate-removal process:

Two cascaded cycles (ordo n^2) that confronts the record ID of each contact-pair that was returned by `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople`. Then I add to the final list only the contact with the *smaller* contact ID. It's not very beautiful solution but it works for me.